# When modifying the Dom, what performs better: to modify many individual small elements or a patterned large element set? How to minimize reflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, reflow

[JSFiddle 2 Question Example](https://jsfiddle.net/oj631ayw/59/)

**Overview:**
I have some javascript that modifies my HTML.  I've noticed that there seems to be a significant slow down when I view the page on mobile devices.  Currently I'm doing this modification at the lowest possible level but it is occurring hundreds to a few thousand times.  Because of the way that the html was generated, the elements that I'm editing are very predictable and follow an easy to foresee pattern.  I'm wondering if because of this pattern nature that it would be faster to do fewer larger DOM modifications:  modifications of an entire set of elements (in block like edits) rather many single low level element edits to the DOM.

Explanations follow the example cases.

**Below is my javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    makeRatingButtons(".RatedSection .Selector", "HL", 8);
}

function makeRatingButtons(SelectorText, Direction, NA, ExcludeText){
    if(typeof ExcludeText === "undefined") {ExcludeText = '';} else {ExcludeText = ":not(" + ExcludeText + ")";}
    var trueSelector = SelectorText + ExcludeText;
    var windowwidth = window.innerWidth;
    $(trueSelector).each(function(){
        var id = $(this)[0].children[0].id;
        var idHash = '#' + id;
        var clickevent = $(this).find('input').attr('onclick');
        var prefix = '<div id="123" class="Wrapper" onclick=triggerCheckActionOf(';
        prefix += "'" + id + "'";
        prefix += ');' + clickevent + ' for="' + id + '">';
        var suffix = '</div>';
        var str='';

        if (Direction == "HL"){
            var index = NA - $(this).find('input').val();
            if(index==0){
                str = prefix + 'NA' + suffix;
            }else if((index == 1 || index == NA-1) && windowwidth<=1000){
                str = prefix + '<abbr title=""><u>' + index.toString() + "</u></abbr>" + suffix;
            }else{
                str = prefix + index.toString() + suffix;
            }
        }else{
            var index = $(this).find('input').val();
            if(index==NA){
                str = prefix + 'NA' + suffix;
            }else if((index == 1 || index == NA-1) && windowwidth<=1000){
                str = prefix + '<abbr title=""><u>' + index.toString() + "</u></abbr>" + suffix;
            }else{
                str = prefix + index.toString() + suffix;
            }
        }

        $(idHash).after(str);
    });
};
```

**My HTML before Javascript:**

```
<table id="a71904308a0e47c785d1e41ba4dd0e2c" class="RatedSection">
    <tbody><tr class="Header">
        <td></td>
        <td class="Label Center">Strongly Agree</td>
        <td class="Label Center">Agree</td>
        <td class="Label Center">Somewhat Agree</td>
        <td class="Label Center">Neutral</td>
        <td class="Label Center">Somewhat Disagree</td>
        <td class="Label Center">Disagree</td>
        <td class="Label Center">Strongly Disagree</td>
        <td class="Label Center">N/A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Header_Numbers">
        <td></td>
        <td class="Number Center">7</td>
        <td class="Number Center">6</td>
        <td class="Number Center">5</td>
        <td class="Number Center">4</td>
        <td class="Number Center">3</td>
        <td class="Number Center">2</td>
        <td class="Number Center">1</td>
        <td class="Number NA"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="bdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b" class="RatedQuest">
        <td class="RatedQuest"><span class="QuestText">Overall, I would recommend this place to family and friends</span></td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_1" name="nrb_bdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b" value="1" onclick="">
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_2" name="nrb_bdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b" value="2" onclick="">
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_3" name="nrb_bdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b" value="3" onclick="">
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_4" name="nrb_bdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b" value="4" onclick="">
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_5" name="nrb_bdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b" value="5" onclick="">
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_6" name="nrb_bdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b" value="6" onclick="">
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_7" name="nrb_bdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b" value="7" onclick="">
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_8" name="nrb_bdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b" value="8" onclick="">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68" class="RatedQuest Alt">
        <td class="RatedQuest"><span class="QuestText">Overall, my experience was a good value for the price paid</span></td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_1" name="nrb_04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68" value="1" onclick="">
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_2" name="nrb_04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68" value="2" onclick="">
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_3" name="nrb_04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68" value="3" onclick="">
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_4" name="nrb_04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68" value="4" onclick="">
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_5" name="nrb_04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68" value="5" onclick="">
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_6" name="nrb_04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68" value="6" onclick="">
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_7" name="nrb_04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68" value="7" onclick="">
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_8" name="nrb_04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68" value="8" onclick="">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

**My HTML after Javascript:**

```
<table id="a71904308a0e47c785d1e41ba4dd0e2c" class="RatedSection">
    <tbody><tr class="Header">
        <td></td>
        <td class="Label Center">Strongly Agree</td>
        <td class="Label Center">Agree</td>
        <td class="Label Center">Somewhat Agree</td>
        <td class="Label Center">Neutral</td>
        <td class="Label Center">Somewhat Disagree</td>
        <td class="Label Center">Disagree</td>
        <td class="Label Center">Strongly Disagree</td>
        <td class="Label Center">N/A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="Header_Numbers">
        <td></td>
        <td class="Number Center">7</td>
        <td class="Number Center">6</td>
        <td class="Number Center">5</td>
        <td class="Number Center">4</td>
        <td class="Number Center">3</td>
        <td class="Number Center">2</td>
        <td class="Number Center">1</td>
        <td class="Number NA"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="bdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b" class="RatedQuest">
        <td class="RatedQuest"><span class="QuestText">Overall, I would recommend this place to family and friends</span></td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_1" name="nrb_bdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b" value="1" onclick=""><div id="123" class="Wrapper" onclick="triggerCheckActionOf('rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_1');" for="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_1">7</div>
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_2" name="nrb_bdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b" value="2" onclick=""><div id="123" class="Wrapper" onclick="triggerCheckActionOf('rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_2');" for="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_2">6</div>
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_3" name="nrb_bdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b" value="3" onclick=""><div id="123" class="Wrapper" onclick="triggerCheckActionOf('rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_3');" for="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_3">5</div>
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_4" name="nrb_bdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b" value="4" onclick=""><div id="123" class="Wrapper" onclick="triggerCheckActionOf('rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_4');" for="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_4">4</div>
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_5" name="nrb_bdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b" value="5" onclick=""><div id="123" class="Wrapper" onclick="triggerCheckActionOf('rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_5');" for="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_5">3</div>
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_6" name="nrb_bdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b" value="6" onclick=""><div id="123" class="Wrapper" onclick="triggerCheckActionOf('rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_6');" for="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_6">2</div>
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_7" name="nrb_bdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b" value="7" onclick=""><div id="123" class="Wrapper" onclick="triggerCheckActionOf('rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_7');" for="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_7">1</div>
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_8" name="nrb_bdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b" value="8" onclick=""><div id="123" class="Wrapper" onclick="triggerCheckActionOf('rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_8');" for="rabdf9ed2961164d3a8bc27012c74af40b_8">NA</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68" class="RatedQuest Alt">
        <td class="RatedQuest"><span class="QuestText">Overall, my experience was a good value for the price paid</span></td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_1" name="nrb_04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68" value="1" onclick=""><div id="123" class="Wrapper" onclick="triggerCheckActionOf('ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_1');" for="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_1">7</div>
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_2" name="nrb_04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68" value="2" onclick=""><div id="123" class="Wrapper" onclick="triggerCheckActionOf('ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_2');" for="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_2">6</div>
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_3" name="nrb_04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68" value="3" onclick=""><div id="123" class="Wrapper" onclick="triggerCheckActionOf('ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_3');" for="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_3">5</div>
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_4" name="nrb_04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68" value="4" onclick=""><div id="123" class="Wrapper" onclick="triggerCheckActionOf('ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_4');" for="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_4">4</div>
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_5" name="nrb_04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68" value="5" onclick=""><div id="123" class="Wrapper" onclick="triggerCheckActionOf('ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_5');" for="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_5">3</div>
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_6" name="nrb_04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68" value="6" onclick=""><div id="123" class="Wrapper" onclick="triggerCheckActionOf('ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_6');" for="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_6">2</div>
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_7" name="nrb_04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68" value="7" onclick=""><div id="123" class="Wrapper" onclick="triggerCheckActionOf('ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_7');" for="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_7">1</div>
        </td>
        <td class="Selector">
        <input type="radio" id="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_8" name="nrb_04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68" value="8" onclick=""><div id="123" class="Wrapper" onclick="triggerCheckActionOf('ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_8');" for="ra04bb8a8fce6f42a58fedcc69379cec68_8">NA</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

**My CSS that matters:**

```
.RatedSection .RatedQuest .Wrapper{
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-color: #D6D5D5;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    transition-duration: 0.4s;
    font-size: 16px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    width: 25px;
}

input {
    display: none;
}
```

**Simple Explanation:**
So basically I have a website that has a form that gets some information about stuff.  There is some black boxed code that generates the HTML to ask questions and it makes it in the way shown in the 'before javascript' example.  What my javascript code does is it adds in a div following the input element within each selector div.  There are some special rules for the first and last selector to give the user some context, but that that isn't important for this question.  Looking at the waterfall it seems that as things are, there are many "Recalculate Style" steps.  This is reflow.  Should I go through the process of updating entire "RatedQuest" div classes, should I expect to see a lower reflow cost?

**What matters to me:**
Currently I'm sitting at around ~17 seconds of waiting after the first render of the page to reflect (update the draw with) the changes that the javascript produces on a Note 3.  I think I could tolerate something like 5 seconds, but would I have reason to believe using a broader DOM update would decrease redraw time, or is there something else I should be thinking of?

**Numbers that may matter to you:**
I should note in the case that I have issue with this, there are 600+ instance of these questions.  With that many questions I'm looking at 8*600+ or 4800+ executions from the "$(trueSelector).each".

**Disclaimer:**
For reasons beyond my control (permissions & bureaucracy) I don't have access to the html source, only to a system that can inject link tags.  So I can't directly edit the html to make it what I want, but I can write some javascript to change the html.  I know the easiest and best solution is just to edit the HTML to what I want and not use any javascript, but I don't have that luxury.

**Thank you!**
Anyone that has any insight into this, I greatly appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: One simple helpful thing, is that everytime you call `$(this)` you initiate a new jQuery object, which takes time. Just alias it once `var $this = $(this);`

Comment: Thanks I'll make that modification.

Comment: So I'm looking at ~13.5 seconds redraw time now which is a good start to improvement.  If I can shave ~10 seconds off, I'd be happy.

Comment: It's really tough to say given that the markup you've shown is undoubtedly far smaller than the real markup. Can you make a `jsFiddle` that shows all the relevant markup? Even if it's thousands of lines (the HTML most specifically).

Comment: Turns out jquery is slow and sucks.  Works much faster with pure javascript.